# Passing object to Excel VBA Sub results in Argument not Optional Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Sub:

```
Public Function Log(sdsMessage As CStandardPropertySet2)
' Only print the fields contained int he sdsMessage
End Function
```

and I use it like this:

```
Log(anSdsMessage)
```

However this results in the `Argument not optional` error.

But if I have the sub like this:

```
Public Function Log(sdsMessage As CStandardPropertySet2) As CStandardPropertySet2
' Only print the fields contained int he sdsMessage
Set Log = sdsMessage
End Function

Set anSdsMessage = Log(anSdsMessage)
```

Then the error disappears. This looks very awkward to me as I do not need to modify the message at all and only want to print the fields in it.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do your functions have `End Sub` and not `End Function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is silly confusing VBA syntax. when you are jsut calling `Log` as a method and have no return type you omit the parentheses.

so `Log anSdsMessage` when no return value is set

and (correctly as you have it already) `Set anSdsMessage = Log(anSdsMessage)` when a return value is set.

To address Daniel's comment

I can write this code

```
Public Function Log(sdsMessage As Collection)
' Only print the fields contained int he sdsMessage
End Function

Sub tester()
    Dim o As Collection
    Set o = New Collection
    Log (o)
End Sub
```

And try to run the `tester` sub and I get the error message "Compile error: Argument not optional"

Removing the parentheses and running `Log o` does in fact allow compilation and removes the error.

Comment: Omitting the parenthesis alone should not resolve the issue. A function which returns a value can be run with or without the parenthesis. However, if run without the parenthesis, the return value cannot be used and will throw an error if an attempt is made to use it. More specifically, if the function returns "no value" if run with the parenthesis, it actually returns an empty variant.

Comment: But his function does not have a return value.

Comment: That's true, but it should have no bearing on a Argument Not Optional error.

Comment: Try the code I just posted into my answer. You'll see, this is definitely the problem.

Comment: +1, Good defense and explanation. It's nice being proven wrong so well. I had been trying to replicate what you were saying but made the mistake of passing variables that weren't complicated enough.

Comment: Thank you. and yeah, if you pass strings or ints it doesn't give the same error. Kind of tricky like that :)